pango.pc not found even though PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is configured
RHEL 9.4 does not have the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable configured even though pkg-config is installed. Therefore, cargo cannot build pango-sys because the pango.pc file is needed. Setting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig still does not work, even though pango.pc file is in that directory.
PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable was to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig because the pango.pc file is in that directory. However, cargo run still says that it cannot find the pango.pc file, even though it now recognizes the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is pointed to the correct location.
[joshuasmartin@customer books]$ cargo run
   Compiling glib-sys v0.19.5
   Compiling gobject-sys v0.19.5
   Compiling gio-sys v0.19.5
   Compiling pango-sys v0.19.5
   Compiling cairo-sys-rs v0.19.2
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf-sys v0.19.5
   Compiling gdk4-sys v0.8.2
   Compiling graphene-sys v0.19.5
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: pango-sys@0.19.5: 

error: failed to run custom build command for `pango-sys v0.19.5`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/joshuasmartin/Projects/books/target/debug/build/pango-sys-b0e0c14daac28167/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PANGO_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:warning=
  pkg-config exited with status code 1
  > PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags pango pango >= 1.49.2

  The system library `pango` required by crate `pango-sys` was not found.
  The file `pango.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains the following:
      - 
      - /usr/lib64/pkgconfig

  HINT: you may need to install a package such as pango, pango-dev or pango-devel.

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...


I'm thinking that the issue is RHEL 9.4 has version 1.48.7 of pango installed rather than the "greater than or equal to 1.49.2" that the cflags specify. Not sure how to modify those cflags, though.

Resolved the issue by disabling pkg-config lookup of system-deps in the Cargo.toml and specifying the shared object name of pango according the instructions here:
https://docs.rs/system-deps/1.3.2/system_deps/#overriding-build-flags
Added the following lines to .bashrc and now the cargo run is successful:
export SYSTEM_DEPS_PANGO_NO_PKG_CONFIG="true"
export SYSTEM_DEPS_PANGO_LIB="pango-1.0"

